# Unable to call functions from a class in python. Learning python the hardway ex49

Tags: python

I am doing Learning Python the hard way [ex48](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex49.html). The following is my code:

```
class ParserError(Exception):
    pass

class Sentence(object):

    def __init__(self, subject, verb, obj):
        self.subject = subject[1]
        self.verb = verb[1]
        self.object = obj[1]

    def peek(word_list):
        if word_list:
            word = word_list[0]
            return word[0]
        else:
            return None

    def match(word_list, expecting):
        if word_list:
            word = word_list.pop(0)
            if word[0] == expecting:
                return word
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def skip(word_list, word_type):
        while peek(word_list) == word_type:
            match(word_list, word_type)


    def parse_verb(word_list):
        skip(word_list, 'stop')

        if peek(word_list) == 'verb':
            return match(word_list, 'verb')
        else:
            raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")

    def parse_object(word_list):
        skip(word_list, 'stop')
        next_word = peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'noun':
            return match(word_list, 'noun')
        elif next_word == 'direction':
            return match(word_list, 'direction')
        else:
            raise ParserError("Expected a noun or direction next")

    def parse_subject(word_list):
        skip(word_list, 'stop')
        next_word = peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'noun':
            return match(word_list, 'noun')
        elif next_word == 'verb':
            return ('noun', 'player')
        else:
            raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")

    def parse_sentence(word_list):
        subj = parse_subject(word_list)
        verbj = parse_verb(word_list)
        obj = parse_object(word_list)

        return Sentence(subj, verb, obj)
```

I am trying to run this script in the terminal. I ran python3 and first imported the script then tried to run one of the function. However, I am getting the following errors:

[image]

I would like to know how can I can this function from the class correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean `self.parse_subject` - it's an instance method, not a function.

Comment: Looking at the exercise in question, they are supposed to be functions not methods - you have an indentation problem.

Comment: Since the functions declared inside class 'Sentence' are not class functions, you cannot call them by using the class name, e.g. `Sentence.parse_sentence(...)`.

Comment: I realized the indentation problem is exactly the cause of my error. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with classes, your functions will look a little different. The first parameter in the function definition will refer to the object itself, and is usually called `self` as you did in `__init__`. Add a `self` parameter to each additional instance method, and then use other parameters (like `word_list`) as needed. Then refer to these instance methods with `self.method_name`.

```
def parse_subject(self, word_list):
    self.skip(word_list, 'stop')
    next_word = self.peek(word_list)

    if next_word == 'noun':
        return self.match(word_list, 'noun')
    elif next_word == 'verb':
        return ('noun', 'player')
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a verb next.")
```

The above is just a sample - you will need to modify the other instance methods in similar ways.

Answer (score 1):

adding to TigerhawkT3's answer - you will need also to initialize the class first and only then call the method:

```
s = Sentence(subject, verb, object)
subj = s.parse_subject(word_list)
```